# casting error while dynamically invoking a function that returns a custom type

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I have a class, named customType, in the namespace tool1.

I am using some other method (of class1 in the namespace tool1), named routine1 - that returns a "List of customType", as follows.

This code returns a list of customtype with no errors:

```
    List<tool1.class1.customType> result1 = new List<tool1.class1.customType>();
    result1 = tool1.class1.routine1(argsAsStr, p_values);
```

The following code also works fine with no errors and returns an object, as follows:

```
    Assembly tool1 = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\tool1\tool1\bin\Debug\tool1.dll");
    Type type = tool1.GetType("tool1.class1");
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    object[] parametersArray = new object[] { argsAsStr, p_values};
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("routine1");
    object result2 = method.Invoke(instance, parametersArray);
```

However, when I try to cast the result as List, instead of object, I receive a casting error:

```
    Assembly tool1 = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\tool1\tool1\bin\Debug\tool1.dll");
    Type type = tool1.GetType("tool1.class1");
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    object[] parametersArray = new object[] { argsAsStr, p_values};
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("routine1");
    List<tool1.class1.customType> result2 = method.Invoke(instance, parametersArray)
```

Error message:

```
Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<tool1.class1.customType>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

How can I overcome this casting error, and, hopefully, return "not" an object but "a list of customType" after invoke method??

Thanks in advance for your interest and contributions,

Aykut

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "under tool1.class1" for example? It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve]. (I'd also strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet for the tip. I will do that and edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to cast the result of `method.Invoke` (which returns `object`):

```
var result2 = (List<tool1.class1.customType>)method.Invoke(instance, parametersArray);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried this casting after your suggestion but did not work out. I will dig more and provide you with detailed error message. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Your "method" is returning a single instance of your custom type not a list of that type.

Try:

```
List<tool1.class1.customType> result2 = new List<tool1.class1.customType>();
result2.Add(method.Invoke(instance, parametersArray));
```

Comment: Problem is that `MethodInfo.Invoke` returns `object`. Need to cast the result to his intended type.